# Font on my AMOLED display has white border

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, screen, fonts, super-amoled

I noticed that text on my Galaxy S3 is bad looking.

*This is how it should look*

[image: This is how it should look]

*And this is how it is looking*
[image]

On the second image you can see white border around every letter..

**But**, when I change display mode to *Natural* or *Movie*, the border there is not. Is it right? Does it mean that the display is corrupted?

I bought this phone few days ago as used. The phone was made 2 years and 2 months ago but I don't know how long it the previous owner was using. Display is without any scratch, blue colour is okay. The phone is looking as unused.

thanks for help

Comment: It's caused by the display mode, it's basically an equalizer for images.

Answer (score 0):

If i adjust brightness and saturation on your first image:

[image: adjust brightness and saturation]

**White border is visible!**
It's really hard to say. 
I think this occurs because the adjustments is very different in each display mode.
Which mode have you used in second image?

Comment: Oh. I didnt noticed this. I used dynamic mode